# Clojure equality of collections with sequences

Tags: clojure, sequence, equality

I noticed that Clojure (1.4) seems to be happy to consider vectors equal to the `seq` of the same vector, but that the same does not apply for maps:

```
(= [1 2] (seq [1 2]))
=> true

(= {1 2} (seq {1 2}))
=> false
```

Why should the behaviour of `=` be different in this way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clojure's `=` can be thought of as performing its comparisons in two steps:

1. Check if the types of the things being compared belong to the same "equality partition", that is a class of types whose members might potentially be equal (depending on things like the exact members of a given data structure, but not the particular type in the partition);
2. If so, check if the things being compared actually are equal.

One such equality partition is that of "sequential" things. Vectors are considered sequential:

```
(instance? clojure.lang.Sequential [])
;= true
```

As are seqs of various types:

```
(instance? clojure.lang.Sequential (seq {1 2}))
;= true
```

Therefore a vector is considered equal to a seq if (and only if) their corresponding elements are equal.

(Note that `(seq {})` produces `nil`, which is *not* sequential and compares "not equal" to `()`, `[]` etc.)

On the other hand, maps constitute an equality partition of their own, so while a hash map might be considered equal to a sorted map, it will never be considered equal to a seq. In particular, it is not equal to the seq of its entries, which is what `(seq some-map)` produces.

Answer (score 5):

I guess this is because in sequences order as well as value at particular position matters where as in map the  order of key/value doesn't matter and this difference between semantics causes this to work as shown by your sample code.

For more details have a look at `mapEquals` in file https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentMap.java

It checks if the other object is not map then return false.

Answer (score 3):

```
user=> (seq {1 2})
([1 2])
user=> (type {1 2})
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this example points out a slight inconsistency in the notion of equality of values in clojure for this case where they are different types derived from the same type (by the `seq` function). It could well be argued that this is not inconsistent because it is comparing a derived type to the type it is derived from and I can understand that if the same logic was applied to this same example using vectors (note at the bottom)

the contents are the same type:

```
user> (type (first (seq {1 2})))
clojure.lang.MapEntry
user> (type (first {1 2}))
clojure.lang.MapEntry

user> (= (type (first {1 2})) (type (first (seq {1 2}))))
true
user> (= (first {1 2}) (first (seq {1 2})))
true
```

the sequences have the same values

```
user> (map = (seq {1 2}) {1 2})
(true)
```

but they are not considered equal
    user> (= {1 2} (seq {1 2}))
    false

this is true for longer maps as well:

```
user> (map = (seq {1 2 3 4}) {1 2 3 4})
(true true)
user> (map = (seq {1 2 3 4 5 6}) {1 2 3 4 5 6})
(true true true)
user> (map = (seq {9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6}) {9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6})
(true true true true)
```

**even if they are not in the same order**:

```
user> (map = (seq {9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6}) {1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10})
(true true true true)
```

but again not if the containing types differ :-(

```
user> (= {1 2 3 4} (seq {1 2 3 4}))
false
```

EDIT: this is not always true see below:
to work around this you can **convert everything to a seq before comparison**, which is (I presume) safe because the seq function always iterates the whole data structure the same way  and the structures are immutable values and a `seq` of a `seq` is a `seq`

```
user> (= (seq {9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6}) {1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10})
false
user> (= (seq {9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6}) (seq {1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10}))
true
```

---

vectors are treated differently:

```
user> (= [1 2 3 4] (seq [1 2 3 4]))
true
```

Perhaps understanding the minor inconsistencies is part of learning a language or someday this could be changed (though I would not hold my breath)

---

EDIT:

I found two maps that produce different sequences for the same value so just calling seq on the maps will not give you proper map equality:

```
user> (seq (zipmap  [3 1 5 9][4 2 6 10]))
([9 10] [5 6] [1 2] [3 4])
user> (seq {9 10 5 6 1 2 3 4})
([1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [9 10])
user>
```

here is an example of what I'm calling proper map equality:

```
user> (def a (zipmap  [3 1 5 9][4 2 6 10]))
#'user/a
user> (def b {9 10 5 6 1 2 3 4})
#'user/b
user> (every? true? (map #(= (a %) (b %)) (keys a)))
true
```

Answer (score 1):

`(seq some-hash-map)` gives you a sequence of entries (key/value pairs).

For example:

```
foo.core=> (seq {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
([:a 1] [:c 3] [:b 2])
```

which is not the same as `[:a 1 :b 2 :c 3]`.