# Clojure can a list be identical to a vector

Tags: clojure

In REPL, when you input

```
(= [1 2 3] (list 1 2 3))
```

You'll get a **true**. Does it mean that a list can be identical with a vector?

Comment: Their contents are identical. Their types are not, same goes for internal representation in memory, access methods etc.

Comment: related or duplicate: [Clojure equality of collections with sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995655/clojure-equality-of-collections-with-sequences)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a `clojure.lang.PersistentList` can never be `identical?` to a `clojure.lang.IPersistentVector` -- they are different types, and obviously objects of different types can not be the same object.  Therefore they can not be identical.

They *can*, however, be equal.  `=` in Clojure checks equality, not identity, and calls the `equals` method that every `Object` has in Java.  Both lists and vectors implement `equals` by determining whether the *contents* of the list/vector are `equal` to the contents of the other collection (if the other object is not a collection, it will return `false`).

Comment: Broadly true, but `=` doesn't call `equals` on collections, because Java's `equals` mandates a contract that is unpleasant from Clojure's point of view. It calls a Clojure-specific method, `pcequiv`, which stands for Persistent Collection Equivalent.